# C# APP freezes during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is the code, I have tested the snmpconn method in a commandline application it works but it freezes during runtime in windows form application, I have no reason why ?

```
 public snmpmain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.snmpconn);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //button1.Enabled = false; will disable the button before the event is fired
       this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.snmpconn);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

        int port = 162;
       // UdpClient listener;
    //    IPEndPoint groupEP;
        byte[] packet = new byte[1024];

        int commlength, miblength, datatype, datalength, datastart, Objecttype, Objectlength;
        int agent;
        int timestamp;
        int entrspc;
        int specifictrap;
        int finallen;
        int objectstart;
        string objectid;
        string test1;
        byte[] test2 = new byte[1024];
        int temp;
        string tempo;


      private void snmpconn(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Initializing" + port + "...");
            this.button1.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.snmpconn);

            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(port);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            while (true)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Waiting....");

                    packet = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);


                listBox1.Items.Add("Processing...");
                if (packet.Length != 0)
                { // do some work 
                  }
             }
         }
```

This works well with command line application.

Do you have a clue .

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Sorry but, were not here to debug your code for you.

Comment: this isn't a forum, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92110#92110

Comment: if you could give a specific error message, stack trace, etc then we would be able to help you more. General "here's my code, what's wrong?" questions aren't received well.  So run your code through the debugger and see what blows up :)

Comment: The problem is program freezing hence no error message I think.... I suggest you to check the `while (true)` part first. PS: shall we just focus on the questions not the rules......

Comment: @TIM: on the debugger it's just fine, then only after that I posted here.. I had no clue what was causing it. I will check the while loop

Comment: @Bolu: Thanks for that but it's not the while loop I'm not able to trace it.

Comment: As stated elsewhere, `while (true)` is pretty horrible, but it's especially bad news on the windows message loop thread, which probably explains why your Console App appeared to work. Your Windows application cannot continue to process UI events, as you've tied up the message loop forever.

Comment: Are you sure your listener is receiving anything?  Or is it just sitting and waiting?  `packet = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);`

Comment: Okay then how would you do the sockets thing without a while loop in a windows form

Comment: @TIM: it works with command line, but on the winform the complete app freezes so I'm not able to verify this.

Answer (score 4):

Woah, i answered without noticing the main mistake!!

```
while (true)
```

Please, don't do it, almost never, if you're not sure of what you're doing!!
You're allocating 100% resources of your process while standing in that loop, without ever leaving a single bit of CPU to perform rendering.

You should read & learn about multi-threading & synchronization before an attempt to make your code working fine.

Then, you're binding too much events to your btn click!

This row:

```
   this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.snmpconn);
```

is not necessary on button1_Click event.

Also, playing with binding events on click may be misleading, you could use a flag (true/false) to check whether to perform your function when btn is clicked.

Comment: It's still the same I'm getting hanging problem

Comment: if `while (true)` made it bad, why it worked in command line ?

Comment: it's certainly not the while loop either. It still hangs even after removing it.

Comment: Well, that while(true) loop doesn't ever exit, it goes on forever. In command line it *may* work as a console application is not bound to any rendering UI thread.

Comment: If it still hangs, your thread execution is hanging somewhere (eg. listener.Receive method) so PLEASE call it in a background thread. Look for multi-threading informations.